# What class/method do I use in the Trading Technologies .NET SDK to indicate that I want to run in server side mode?

Tags: algorithmic-trading

Will the application automatically detect which environment that it is in or do you need to tell it?

Answer (score 0):

The API is the same for both client and server side modes.  To initialize your application for server side mode, you initialize your TTAPIOptions instance as follows:

```
// Add your app secret Key here. It looks like: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
string appSecretKey = “Your App Key”;
//Set the environment the app needs to run in here
tt_net_sdk.ServiceEnvironment environment = tt_net_sdk.ServiceEnvironment.UatCert;
tt_net_sdk.TTAPIOptions apiConfig = new tt_net_sdk.TTAPIOptions(
    tt_net_sdk.TTAPIOptions.SDKMode.Server,
    environment,
    appSecretKey,
    5000);
```